# ld warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode

Tags: ios-simulator, ld

The linker for an iOS simulator target I have is reporting the following warning:

```
ld: warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode
```

No line number is given, nor anything else that is actionable. Googling turned up some [Apple open source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-136/src/ld/passes/compact_unwind.cpp), but I'm not groking it.

What does it mean and what can I do to address it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found some information in the [C++ ABI for Itanium docs](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html#base-personality) that sheds some light on what this means.

> The personality routine is the function in the C++ (or other language) runtime library which serves as an interface between the system unwind library and language-specific exception handling semantics.

Extrapolating, this warning indicates that you've got too many kinds of exception handling in the same binary, and at least one of them may fail. Indeed this is exactly what is observed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29646999/476716).

Sadly, there's no clear way to fix this, only workarounds. You can suppress the warning, remove code, rewrite code in a different language, disable a language's exception handing and possibly others.

Comment: for later friends: the link of 'C++ ABI for Itanium docs' had moved to https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html

Comment: @Xueshi feel free to edit the link in the answer

Answer (score 8):

If you have a crash on exception with this warning, i.e. `::terminate()` call on every `throw`, the workaround is to use old dwarf exception-handling tables. Add following flags to **Build Settings/Linking/Other Linker Flags**:

```
-Wl,-keep_dwarf_unwind -Wl,-no_compact_unwind
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try silencing the warning with `-Wl,-no_compact_unwind` for the Other Linker Flags setting. I think it's harmless.

Comment: I think you're right. It's probably saying there's some sort of performance impact, but there's nothing (that anyone has mentioned yet) I can do about it aside from disabling the log like you suggest.

Comment: IMHO one should be aware that turning of the warning does not really solve underlying problem. My guess is that someone has decided that this warning is important.

Only one part the original question is answered, that is how to solve it. However it should be interesting to know what the warning really means.

Comment: Please don't do that.  The suggestion in this answer will turn off compact unwinding entirely rather than disabling the warning (including in the cases where it can be expressed in the compact unwind format).

Comment: That option can cause exception handling to fail entirely in some situations (i.e. will skip the catch and terminate the process instead).

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this issue as well when trying to run on the iOS simulator while my code was running correctly on the device. In my case, it was not a warning but a linker error.

Luckily, i remembered that I added two flags for **luajit** to run correctly following the [instructions of this page](http://luajit.org/install.html) under the section *Embedding LuaJIT*:

**-pagezero_size 10000** **-image_base 100000000**

My guess is that the image_base address is simply out of bounds on the host CPU.

Anyway, removing these settings made it work in my configuration.

So go to your project's settings and look for any hard wired values of this kind if not the same.

Hope this helps,

M