# Mach-O Linker warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linker

I just finished upgrading my project to use Swift 1.2. I've got a new linker warning that I've never seen before.
`ld: warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode`.

It doesn't give an offending file or any additional details. I know how to suppress this warning, but I'd like to know how to fix it. Any thoughts?

This is different from other questions answered because they all explain how to HIDE the warning, none of them explain how to actually fix the problem.

Comment: See this answer: [ld warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150223/ld-warning-too-many-personality-routines-for-compact-unwind-to-encode/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ld warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150223/ld-warning-too-many-personality-routines-for-compact-unwind-to-encode)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have just got the same error.  I was going to suppress it myself - but I get the feeling that is not a good idea.

Comment: Other people have said this is probably just an issue of complexity, so it's probably not _awful_ to suppress it. But I'd prefer not to if it's something thats fixable.