# ld: warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode

Tags: ios, project-structure, xcode6.3, search-path

I just changed the folder structure of the IOS project in Xcode 6.3 and the warning on the image appeared.Solutions already on the internet are appropriate.I have copied the code in one folder and pasted it in another one.Is it some kin[image]

Comment: Strange warning, haven't seen that. . . . but what is the question?

Comment: i want to remove the warning so that the project is clean..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ld warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150223/ld-warning-too-many-personality-routines-for-compact-unwind-to-encode)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here : [ld warning: too many personality routines for compact unwind to encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150223/ld-warning-too-many-personality-routines-for-compact-unwind-to-encode)

Also you can silent this warning by adding -Wl,-no_compact_unwind in build settings flags.